# How to add outline color to the turtles in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

In netlogo I understand that the default shape is the triangle for which we can specify any color available in the color swatch, but is there a way to add black outline to the default turtle shape i.e. if I create a turtle with green color, i want the triangular turtle to have a black border-line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably the Turtle Shapes Editor in the Tools menu. Check out the shape named "Triangle 2" for basically the inverse of what you are after- just swap the colors and you should be set.

Alternatively, you can outline a shape using the lines or polygon tool in the Shapes editor and use the experimental primitive `__set-line-thickness` to alter the displayed weight of the any lines in that turtle.

Once you have the shape you like, you can use `set-default-shape` to make any new turtles use that shape by default.